# Does using repeat spell on hunter's mercy work?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, metamagic

Hunter's mercy is a spell that appeared in several sources, the version we are using is the spell compendium one.

> This transmutation makes a bow strike true. Your first hit with a bow
>   (not including crossbows) in the next round is automatically a
>   critical hit. If you don't hit in the round following the casting of
>   this spell, the effect is wasted.

This spell's duration is **1 round** but its effects are applied during your next round (unlike **True Strike** which has "Duration: see text" and it lasts until the end of your turn in the next round or when its bonus is used).
As far as i know if something lasts 1 round it ends before you take your turn in the next round (well, in general usually something that started on your turn ends before your turn in the round when it's supposed to end...assuming it's supposed to end).

So, my reasoning is that while the spell lasts 1 round, the effect takes place in the next, thus receiving another spell in the next round won't make the second spell override the previous one (as usual when you cast the same spell with the same conditions twice). If my reasoning is correct it should work like this:

**Turn 1:** Cast repeat hunter's mercy
**Before Turn 2:** 1st hunter's mercy spell ends
**Turn 2:** 2nd hunter's mercy is casted, 1st hunter's mercy effect is applied
**Before Turn 3:** 2nd hunter's mercy spell ends
**Turn 3:** 2nd hunter's mercy effect is applied

Is this correct?
PS: The spell is being cast from a wand. No PC Ranger build was harmed in the making of this spell

Comment: The current way of casting it would be through a wand of repeat hunter's mercy. Or better, that's the intention

Comment: Which would imply the existance of a NPC Ranger with the build you just described. Or maybe a Ranger/Cleric with divine metamagic repeat spells which sells such wands. Either way the master is ok with this, i'm just gona pay extra money as it is a rare item to find

Comment: Right, I tend to forget about that way of making items. Anyways adding that now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## That's how it works

The question's assessment of how the 1st-level ranger spell ***hunter's mercy*** [div] (*Spell Compendium* 117) interacts with the metamagic feat **Repeat Spell** (*Complete Arcane* 82–3) is accurate.

The unusual interaction between the *hunter's mercy* spell's entry of *Duration: 1 round* and its description that specifically says, "Your first hit with a bow… in the next round [n.b. not *this* round but *after* the spell's duration expires] is automatically a critical hit," essentially prevents a caster from, for example, benefiting from a second or more *hunter's mercy* spell's effect twice on the round after they're cast, like one *hunter's mercy* spell cast normally and a second a *hunter's mercy* spell cast on the *same* turn using the metamagic feat [Quicken Spell](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#quicken-spell) (*Player's Handbook* 98) (q.v. [Combining Magical Effects](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#combining-magical-effects) (*PH* 171–2)). This interaction of game elements reduces arguments about *double* critical hits, for example, and limits the possibility of reading differently the word *first* in the spell's description because of timing issues.

While the question provides an overview of how this works in play, for clarity, the following is a step-by-step example:

> #### Example
>
> - **Turn 1:** Abe takes a move action to move and, during that move action, takes a free action to draw his *wand of repeat hunter's mercy*. Abe takes a standard action to activate the *wand*, spending 1 of the wand's charges.
> - **Turn 2:** Right before Abe's turn begins, the 1-round duration of the spell *hunter's mercy* expires. At the beginning of Abe's turn, the repeated iteration of the spell *hunter's mercy* is cast on Abe. Abe takes a free action to activate his *glove of the master strategist* to retrieve his bow, takes a free action to swap hands with his bow and his *wand*, and activates his *glove of the master strategist* again to stow the *wand*. Abe takes a full-round action to make a full attack, launching a bunch of arrows at the [roper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roper_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) (*Monster Manual* 215-16) that thought it was concealed across the chasm. Abe's first attack hits and, because of the effect of the spell *hunter's mercy*, is automatically a critical hit.
> - **Turn 3:** Right before Abe's turn begins, the 1-round duration of the repeated iteration spell *hunter's mercy* expires. Abe takes a full-round action to make a full attack, launching a bunch of arrows at that same poor roper. Abe's first attack hits and, because of the effect of the repeated iteration of the spell *hunter's mercy*, is automatically a critical hit. The roper dies.

A *wand of repeat hunter's mercy*, by the way is no small investment—a *repeat hunter's mercy* spell is typically considered a 4th-level spell when made into a magic item, and the modified spell's caster level is typically 7; this makes the price of a *wand of repeat hunter's mercy* typically 21,000 gp… or 420 gp *per charge*.

This isn't an *obscene* amount for a high-level character to spend during combat—a high-level [flasked avenger](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41938/8610) can spend significantly more—, but this kind of investment *is* something that a ranger keeps in his *glove of the master strategist* (*Ghostwalk* 71) (3,600 gp; 0 lbs.) or in the wand chamber (*Dungeonscape* 30, 34) (100 gp; 0 lbs.) of his bow—or even his braid blade (*Dungeon* #120 35) (10 gp; 0.5 lbs.) or another weapon that's always ready—, rather than activating the *wand*, taking a free action to drop it, and recovering it later.